# Count, how many rows will take given text string

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a text String, information about font and row width in pixels. Is it possible to compute, how many rows will take this string.

```
If a word is long, it will be writen in a next row, for example:
some test string    |
very_very_long_word |

and even if there will be many white space

so very_very_long_word <= this can't be on one row
so                  |
very_very_long_word |

and if the word is too long, it will be separated at the end of row:
veryveryverylonglong|
word                |
```

Comment: Is this a fixed width font? Otherwise, this is going to be very tricky.

Comment: Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

Comment: Already, but it only can give me text width undependantly is it 1-word string or many-word string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use different classes

with graphics2D

```
FontRenderContext frc = (( Graphics2D )g).getFontRenderContext();
String s = range.displayName;
float textWidth = (float) font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getWidth();
float textHeight = (float) font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getHeight();
```

or just use FontMetrics

```
FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(font);
int fontHeight = fm.getHeight();
int w = fm.stringWidth("yourstring");
```

Comment: This will give me width of the string, but as i said, if for example, i have a 30-pixels row, 35-pixels word will be separated at 30-pix, BUT: 3 15-pix words will take 3 strings, not 2!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this by something, so i have done it myself:

```
public class LineCalculator {

private static final FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), true, true);
private static  Font font;
private static int lines;

public int calcLines(String str, int width, String fontFamily, int scale)
{
    font = new Font(fontFamily, Font.PLAIN, scale);
    String[] source = str.split(" ");
    String line = "";
    lines = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.length - 1; i++) {
        source[i] += " ";
    }

    for (String word : source) {
        if (font.getStringBounds(line + word, frc).getWidth() > width) {
            lines++;
            line = singleWordCheck(word, width);
        }
        line += word;
    }
    return lines;
}

private String singleWordCheck(String str, int width)
{
    CharSequence chars = str;
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        if (font.getStringBounds(chars.subSequence(0, i).toString(), frc).getWidth() > width) {
            lines++;
            return singleWordCheck(chars.subSequence(i, chars.length() - 1).toString(), width);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

}